# como actualizar un jtable desde otro jframe

Tags: java

¿como puedo actualizar la tabla cuando modifico de otro jframe. es posible ?

tengo un formulario en java Netbeans en el cual  inserto datos y modifico, la acción de modificar la hago en una ventana emergente al hacer click en una fila de un jtable,hasta aquí todo bien pero cuando modifico en la ventana emergente actualizo con un método que se encuentra en la interfaz donde esta el  jtable pero no funciona. les dejo el codigo abajo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    //este metodo lo llamo del jframe 
    public void datos(String opcion){
 DefaultTableModel modelo= new DefaultTableModel();
   modelo.addColumn("rut");
   modelo.addColumn("nombre");
   modelo.addColumn("A.materno");
   modelo.addColumn("A.paterno");
   modelo.addColumn("Fono");
   modelo.addColumn("Nro °casa");
   modelo.addColumn("Calle");
   modelo.addColumn("Sector");
   modelo.addColumn("Comuna");
   modelo.addColumn("T.zapato");
   modelo.addColumn("T.pantalon");
   modelo.addColumn("T.chaqueta");
   modelo.addColumn("Estado");
   modelo.addColumn("Paswword");
   modelo.addColumn("Cargo");
   modelo.addColumn("id_co");
   modelo.addColumn("id_e");
   modelo.addColumn("id_ca");

  ResultSet rs=null;

  try{
    if(opcion=="todo"){
  rs=obj.mostrar();
  }
   else if(opcion=="buscar"){

       obj.setNombre(txtbuscar.getText());
       obj.setRut(txtbuscar.getText());
       obj.setOpcion(buttonGroup1.getSelection().getActionCommand());
   rs=obj.buscar();
  }
    if(rs.next()){
  while(rs.next()){
    Object [] fila= new Object[18];  
    fila[0]=rs.getString("RUT_TRABAJADOR");
    fila[1]=rs.getString("NOMBRE");
    fila[2]=rs.getString("APELLIDO_M");
    fila[3]=rs.getString("APELLIDO_P");
    fila[4]=rs.getInt("TELEFONO");
    fila[5]=rs.getInt("NRO_CALLE");
    fila[6]=rs.getString("CALLE");
    fila[7]=rs.getString("VILLA_POBLACION");
    fila[8]=rs.getString(9);
    fila[9]=rs.getInt("TALLA_CALZADO");
    fila[10]=rs.getInt("TALLA_PANTALON");
    fila[11]=rs.getInt("TALLA_CHAQUETA");
    fila[12]=rs.getString("NOMBRE_ESTADO");
    fila[13]=rs.getString("password");
    fila[14]=rs.getString("NOMBRE_CARGO");
    fila[15]=rs.getString("ID_COMUNA");
    fila[16]=rs.getString("ID_ESTADO");
    fila[17]=rs.getString("ID_CARGO");
    modelo.addRow(fila);
   }
  }

  }catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
tabla.setModel(modelo);





}




 //click del boton de la ventana emergente donde modifico y llamo a la funcion datos que esta en el jframe principal

private void btnmodificarMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
     Mantenedor_insumo m= new Mantenedor_insumo();
     //modificar datos del trabajador


    try{
        obj.setRut(txtrut.getText());
        obj.setNombre(txtnombre.getText());
        obj.setApellido_m(txtapellido_m.getText());
        obj.setApellido_p(txtapellido_p.getText());
        obj.setCalzado(Integer.parseInt(txtzapato.getText()));
        obj.setPantalon(Integer.parseInt(txtpantalon.getText()));
        obj.setChaqueta(Integer.parseInt(txtchaqueta.getText()));
        obj.setFono(Integer.parseInt(txtfono.getText()));
        obj.setNro_calle(Integer.parseInt(txtnro_casa.getText()));
        obj.setCalle(txtcalle.getText());
        obj.setSector(txtsector.getText());
        String  id=combocomuna.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String [] comuna= id.split("-");
        obj.setId_comuna(Integer.parseInt(comuna[0].trim()));
        String id_cargo=lst_cargo.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String [] cargo=id_cargo.split("-");
        obj.setId_cargo(Integer.parseInt(cargo[0].trim()));
        String id_estado=lst_estado.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String [] estado=id_estado.split("-");
        obj.setId_estado(Integer.parseInt(estado[0].trim()));
        obj.setPassword(txtpass.getText());
        obj.modificar();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Datos del trabajador modificado correctamente","Confirmacion",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        m.datos("todo");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("problema en modificar : " + e.getMessage()+ " ");

    }

}       


 //metodo modificar en clase trabajador funciona correctamente
 public void modificar () throws SQLException{
 String sql="UPDATE trabajador set        NOMBRE=?,APELLIDO_M=?,APELLIDO_P=?,TELEFONO=?,CALLE=?,NRO_CALLE=?,"
      + "VILLA_POBLACION=?,TALLA_CALZADO=?,TALLA_PANTALON=?,TALLA_CHAQUETA=?,password=?,"
      + "ID_COMUNA=?,ID_ESTADO=?,ID_CARGO=? WHERE RUT_TRABAJADOR=?";
Connection cn=datasource.getConnection();
PreparedStatement sentencia=cn.prepareStatement(sql);
sentencia.setString(1,getNombre());
sentencia.setString(2,getApellido_m());
sentencia.setString(3,getApellido_p());
sentencia.setInt(4,getFono());
sentencia.setString(5,getCalle());
sentencia.setInt(6,getNro_calle());
sentencia.setString(7,getSector());
sentencia.setInt(8,getCalzado());
sentencia.setInt(9,getPantalon());
sentencia.setInt(10,getChaqueta());
sentencia.setString(11,getPassword());
sentencia.setInt(12, getId_comuna());
sentencia.setInt(13, getId_estado());
sentencia.setInt(14, getId_cargo());
sentencia.setString(15, getRut());

sentencia.executeUpdate();


    System.out.println("sql modificar: "+ sentencia);



}
```

Comment: Por favor, coloca todo el codigo... veo que usas un objeto que llama un metodo "modificar", probablemente por ahi va el asunto...

Comment: @TwoDent ya agrege el metodo para que lo veas

Comment: Dime, el metodo si te actualiza tu base de datos, pero no te actualiza tu JTable... si entiendo bien?

Comment: @TwoDent si eso pasa , es que el modificar lo hago en otra pantalla entonces cuando haga click en el boton modificar quiero que se actualice la tabla que esta en otro jframe. entonces cree un objeto de la ventana principal que contiene un metodo que actualiza la tabla, y lo puse luego de modificar pero no funciona.

Comment: Yo no hago las cosas como lo tienes implementado. Desde mi punto de vista es mejor "almacenar" un objeto en la fila y mostrarlo en las celdas con renders apropiados. Cuando cambies los datos de una fila, deberías cambiar los atributos del objeto. Cuando se acepten los cambios entonces guardas en la BD y haces un `refresh()` de la tabla. En ese momento surgirá la magia que pides. Investiga en Google lo que te digo porque hacer una respuesta con todo eso implementado no entra dentro del formato de este sitio. Entonces podrás pedir soluciones a otros problemas más pequeños que te surjan.

Answer (score 1):

para el próximo que le pase contruye un boton actualizar  en el frame que recive la accion y desde el frame que hace la accion lo enlazamos con nombreframe.nombreboton.doClick(); detrno del boton metemos la tabla o l oque se valla a actualizar y ya

Comment: Buenas Daniel bienvenido Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla. Te recomiendo leer esto [answer] y así mejorar la calidad de tus respuestas y sean mejor valoradas por la comunidad.