# ¿Alguna forma de cambiar los datos de un Jlabel de formulario padre desde un formulario hijo?

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica

[image: ****]
Cambie los atributos privado a publico de los Jlabel pero siguen sin cambiar su contenido y lo hago de esa forma porque hago una impresión del formulario en PDF y por alguna razón no imprime el contenido del JTextfield

Comment: ¿Por qué pusiste el código como imagen?

Comment: He visto que ponen imágenes como referencia talvez ayude de algo o me vayan a bardear xd

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [como actualizar un jtable desde otro jframe](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50852/como-actualizar-un-jtable-desde-otro-jframe)

Comment: Subir código como imagen [es mala idea](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Las imágenes sirven de referencia cuando agregan más contexto al código (en texto) en cuestión, por ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no puedes acceder a los objetos como tal si fueran atributos. Intenta crear una instancia de tipo JLabel obtenida por tu instancia de tipo form. Para ello, puedes crear un get de tipo JLabel y retornar ese JLabel:

```
//En la clase o form donde esta el label a cambiar
public JLabel getMiLabel(){
 return jlabel1; //El nombre de tu label
}

//En la clase donde quieres editar el label
frmDC v = new frmDC();
JLabel jl = v.getMiLabel();
```

Luego, si intenta settear el valor:

```
jl.setText("Nuevo Texto");
```